# How to reset an OpenConnect / NetworkManager pinned certificate

Tags: network-manager, vpn, certificates, openconnect

I have installed an OpenConnect server (ocserv) so I can connect to my home systems.
Initially I used the valid LetsEncrypt provided certificate for `*.example.com`, later I changed that to `vpn.example.com`

I repeatedly used my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop in conjunction with the OpenConnect NetworkManager gui for Gnome to test this while I was setting it up.

The problem I now have is that my laptop is now unable to connect anymore because it consistently fails with

```
Oct  3 23:09:49 X openconnect[2076201]: Connected to 1.2.3.4:443
Oct  3 23:09:49 X openconnect[2076201]: SSL negotiation with 1.2.3.4
Oct  3 23:09:49 X openconnect[2076201]: Server certificate verify failed: signer not found
Oct  3 23:09:49 X openconnect[2076201]: Server SSL certificate didn't match: pin-sha256:2rZ/XXGddfgH/UNCicveUIOI22v6kn1EMVwzMkvlN2Q=
Oct  3 23:09:49 X NetworkManager[2076201]: Creating SSL connection failed
Oct  3 23:09:49 X openconnect[2076201]: SSL connection failure: Error in the certificate.
```

so apparently a certificate is retained and it now fails because the certificate has changed.

The problem I have is that I have not been able to figure out how I can flush this certificate pin.
I have deleted and recreated the VPN definition but this did not fix this.

How do I do get rid of this pinned certificate ?
And where is this stored?

Comment: Start the `Passwords & Keys` app.

Comment: Good suggestion. This does contain all the vpn passwords but I have not been able the pinned certificate in there.

Comment: Look in /etc/ssl/certs?

Comment: That only contains the preinstalled certificates and the ca-certificates.crt that is generated from these files.